# Getting a JDBC connection by JNDI in Spring JDBC

Tags: spring, jdbc, jndi, spring-jdbc

This [page on Spring JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html) says

> The DataSourceUtils class … provides static methods to obtain connections from JNDI

However [the API doc for DataSourceUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html) does not include the said static methods, as far as I can see.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm... Somehow, the Javadoc of `DataSourceUtils` is more "accurate" (I mean, the doc is not wrong but technically, you obtain a connection from a DataSource - that can be obtained via JNDI):

> Helper class that provides static methods for obtaining JDBC Connections from a [`DataSource`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html).

And the following methods should be what you're looking for:

- [`DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSource)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#getConnection%28javax.sql.DataSource%29)
- [`DataSourceUtils.getGetConnection(DataSource)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#doGetConnection%28javax.sql.DataSource%29)

Basic example (from the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee.html)):

```
// Create a new application context. this processes the Spring config
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ex1appContext.xml");
// Retrieve the data source from the application context
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.getBean("dataSource");
// Open a database connection using Spring's DataSourceUtils
Connection c = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(ds);
try {
    // retrieve a list of three random cities
    PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(
        "select City.Name as 'City', Country.Name as 'Country' " +
        "from City inner join Country on City.CountryCode = Country.Code " +
        "order by rand() limit 3");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        String city = rs.getString("City");
        String country = rs.getString("Country");
        System.out.printf("The city %s is in %s%n", city, country);
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    // something has failed and we print a stack trace to analyse the error
    ex.printStackTrace();
    // ignore failure closing connection
    try { c.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { }
} finally {
    // properly release our connection
    DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(c, ds);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As I understand, what would be really useful to you is [JndiObjectFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectFactoryBean.html). This Spring factory bean returns object published in JNDI.

You would configure it like this, and then you would get the `Connection` using `DataSourceUtils` on the injected `DataSource`:

```
<bean name="myDataSourceInJndi" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDataSource</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="myBean" class="MyClass">
...
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSourceInJndi">        
...
</bean>
```

Comment: hi, I am new to spring, and I would like to know if I am using the method you mentioned above, where do I store the `username` and `password` for my connection?

Answer (score 0):

For further future references: the jndi is managed on the application server i.e. : standalone.xml (Wildfly) with Postgresql driver:

```
 <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDataSource" pool-name="myDS" enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql:[<//host>[:<5432>/]]<database></connection-url>
                <driver>postgresql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>$USER</user-name>
                    <password>$PWD</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
```